# Shared variable in base fragment class, public or private?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a base class fragment (as shown below). I extend this class in 3 other fragment classes, each of which share the same `EditText` that needs to be accessed in these 3 fragments. For this reason, I have the `EditText` variable set up in the base class (so I don't have to call it 3 times, once in each fragment).

Should this variable be `public` or should it be `private` with a getter method set up? Why?

Here is my base class fragment:

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
    public EditText editText;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(getFragmentLayout(), container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    }

    protected abstract int getFragmentLayout();
}
```

Comment: private methods/fields are cannot be. You can use protected instead...inherited.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-difference-between-default-public-protected-and-private?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `editText` is going to be used by sub classes of `BaseFragment` class then you need to mark it as `protected`.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)'s the javadoc, this is what is says:

> The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed
>   within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by
>   a subclass of its class in another package.

By doing this, sub classes won't need to use `getters` and `setters` methods to access this property. They will be able to use it as if it was defined in those classes only. However, for any class that is not in `BaseFragment`'s package or doesn't extend `BaseFragment`, this property will be `private`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only accessing it from `BaseFragment` and its child classes, it can be `Protected`. This will restrict access to only itself and classes that extend it.

```
protected EditText editText;
```

See [this document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for more details about accessibility.